# Is EnableHeaderChecking=true enough to prevent Http Header Injection attacks?

Tags: asp.net, iis, security, fortify

Is it sufficient to have [`System.Web.Configuration.HttpRuntimeSection.EnableHeaderChecking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableheaderchecking(VS.85).aspx) set to `true` (default) to fully prevent Http Header Injection attacks like Response Splitting etc.?

I'm asking because a white box penetration testing tool (fortify) reports exploitable http header injection issues with `HttpResponse.Redirect` and cookies but I haven't found a way to successfully perform an attack. (**edit**:..and we have EnableHeaderChecking turned on..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been looking at this for some time now and draw the conclusion that setting [EnableHeaderChecking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableheaderchecking(VS.85).aspx) to `true` is in fact good enough to prevent http header injection attacks.

Looking at 'reflected' ASP.NET code, I found that:

1. There is only one way to add custom HTTP headers to an HTTP response, namely using the [HttpResponse.AppendHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader.aspx) method
2. [HttpResponse.AppendHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader.aspx) either

   - creates instances of `HttpResponseHeader` (internal)
   - or calls `HttpResponseHeader.MaybeEncodeHeader` (for `IIS7WorkerRequests`)
   - or assigns its respective properties (for known headers like [RedirectLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectlocation.aspx) or [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx))
3. `HttpResponseHeader` instances are created before known headers like [RedirectLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectlocation.aspx) or [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx) are sent (`HttpResponse.GenerateResponseHeaders`)
4. The `HttpResponseHeader` constructor checks the [EnableheaderChecking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableheaderchecking(VS.85).aspx) setting and calls `HttpResponseHeader.MaybeEncodeHeader` when set to `true`
5. `HttpResponseHeader.MaybeEncodeHeader` correctly encodes newline characters which makes HTTP header injection attacks impossible

Here is a snippet to roughly demonstrate how I tested:

```
// simple http response splitting attack
Response.AddHeader("foo", "bar\n" + 
    // injected http response, bad if user provided
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n" + 
    "Content-Length: 19\n" +
    "Content-Type: text/html\n\n" +
    "<html>danger</html>"
);
```

The above only works if you explicitly turn [EnableHeaderChecking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableheaderchecking(VS.85).aspx) off:

```
<httpRuntime enableHeaderChecking="false"/>
```

Fortify simply doesn't take configuration into account (setting [EnableHeaderChecking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.enableheaderchecking(VS.85).aspx) explicitly had no effect) and thus *always* reports these type of issues.

Comment: Hi Josef the code for testing the injection that you wrote above.
I need to where we can paste this code to test my application. I need to test my application as well. thnx

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's enough and it should be turned on by default.

I think Fortify is just thinking about defence in depth as if you change the configuration in the deployment etc.

I assume you did not strictly set it on in your configuration, if you have maybe Fortify is not that smart to figure that our.

**Best way to confirm is exploiting it :)**

- Just get a copy of fiddler
- Intercept the request
- Try to inject new line
- See if the new line you've just injected is in the HTTP response or not.

Comment: (: trust me, I've tried to exploit this. And there are better tools than fiddler, I personally like Charles and the Tamper Data Firefox add-on.

Answer (score 0):

EnableHeaderChecking is only for untrusted data. If you're passing data directly from a cookie into a Redirect, maybe the resulting headers are considered trusted and \r\n values aren't escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Josef, HttpResponse.AppendHeader() is not the only place where untrusted data can enter the HTTP Response Headers.

Any data from the attacker that ends up in Cookies or HTTP redirects can write new headers if the data contains a carriage return (or anything that is interpreted as a carriage return).

In general, it's a much better use of your time to validate your data than to sit around and try to work out exploits.  Chances are, the hackers are going to be better at this than you or I are.

Comment: For well known Headers like Cookies or Redirects, ASP.NET already has checks in place (e.g. have a look at the reflected `HttpResponse.Redirect`), but *custom* headers all go through `AppendHeader`. Of course we do our best to validate data but since Fortify showed Response Splitting Attacks and others we looked at `EnableHeaderChecking`.