# Http header injection test

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, configuration

How can you test Http header injection in your application? I want to see what is the diff after adding enableheader=false in config and before in my application.

Framework .NET 2.0
Language C#
Platform: Windows XP

Comment: What platform, language, framework, etc.?  ASP.net? If you tag your question with what technology you are using you are more likely to get more responses.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869361/is-enableheadercheckingtrue-enough-to-prevent-http-header-injection-attacks

Comment: @alice7 Clarify your question - from your comment to Alconja's answer it sounds as if you want to test your site for vulnerability to HTTP Injection Attack. That is not what your question is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually test it by inspecting the header request/response with a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (an article about how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446(VS.85).aspx)), or using a Firefox add-on like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) or [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829).

Comment: so i installed fiddler and tried running on my application.
I got some HTTP responses back.But how would I know about http header injection from fiddler.Is there anything I need to see which tells me that this page is vulnerable to http header injection.

Comment: The tools I provided simply allow you to view the header information being sent to/from your web application, they won't tell you if you're vulnerable to a http header injection attack. I misunderstood your question & thought you were making changes to your application and just wanted to see what impact that had on the http headers.